# Localization on _Layout.cshtml

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core

I'm trying to apply localization on _Layout.cshtml

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization

@inject Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.JavaScriptSnippet JavaScriptSnippet
@inject IViewLocalizer LayoutLocalizer


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
    <body>
        <div style="margin:38px;margin-top:56px;" class="hidden-sm-down">
            <h2>@LayoutLocalizer["WelcomeHeader"] <b class="text_border_darkblue">MyTitle</b></h2>
            <div style="text-align:center;margin-top:42px;">
                @LayoutLocalizer["WelcomeSub"]
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The resource files are named named: **Views.Shared._Layout.no.resx** (I've tried renaming to *views.shared.Layout.no.resx* without any luck)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution

> Implement SharedResources with resource files and use Localization on
>   the SharedResources object in shared Views

Comment: Links is no valied anymore

Answer (score 8):

You must create a _Layout.no.resx file within the same path of the views but as a root the "Resources" folder. See sample image:

[image]

There is a video clarifying the use of Location see [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=33okCuCK3Ik)

Answer (score 0):

You can combine `IViewLocalizer` and `IHtmlLocalizer` for `_Layout.cshtml`. If you define a resource folder inside your Visual Studio solution you can put the resource files there.

If you are using razor pages instead of MVC views inside your ASP.net core application you create a subfolder Pages instead of Views inside the folder Resources. Put the `_Layout.no.resx` file in there. e.g. `Resources\Pages\_Layout.no.resx`.